# Facebook API: get adAccount campaigns by ids

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

How to get multiple campaigns insights but filter the campaigns by id.
I find it how to get multiple campaigns and insights in one request:

```
GET facebookapi/{adAccountId}/campaigns?fields=name,status,insights{impressions,reach,clicks,cpm,cpc,ctr}
```

But this will return only 25 or I can add a limit of 100 and get the first 100.
What I want to do is to query by campaigns ids. Because I already have the list of campaigns.

Something like that

```
GET facebookapi/{adAccountId}/campaigns?fields=name,status,insights{impressions,reach,clicks,cpm,cpc,ctr}&filter=id{id1,id2,id3}
```

Is this possible with Facebook API?

Comment: Don’t go via `/{adAccountId}/campaigns` then, but put the campaign IDs in directly using `ids=…` syntax - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#multiidlookup

Comment: @CBroe Cool! Very interesting!

Answer (score 2):

You could pass the filtering params as example:

```
act_<ID>/campaigns?fields=name,status,insights{impressions,reach,clicks,cpm,cpc,ctr}&filtering=[{'field':'id','operator':'IN','value':[<campaign_id1>,<campaign_id2>,....]}]
```

Hope this help